# MySql benchmark written in Java

Tags: mysql, benchmark, jdbc

I want to compare the performance of two MySql servers.

Since we are accessing the database using Java/JDBC, the benchmark should be written in Java.
It does not have to be MySql specififc, any compatible JDBC program will do.

Oh, and it should be free (as in beer). Thanks!

Comment: Odd, we have to pay for beer where I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [BenchmarkSQL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/benchmarksql/)

It's JDBC, and it's free as in free and free as in beer.

And a nice [Oracle](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Database+Benchmarking)  page on benchmarking.